# Alfresco share add user to group not found

Tags: alfresco, alfresco-share

I use alfresco 4.2.0. I create a user and will add to the group from admin console
but user not found I try to restart server but not working

[user not found](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sRyCK.jpg)

```
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:10 +0700] "POST /solr/alfresco/afts?wt=json&fl=DBID%2Cscore&rows=250&df=_PERSON&start=0&locale=th&alternativeDic=DEFAULT_DICTIONARY&fq=%7B%21afts%7DAUTHORITY_FILTER_FROM_JSON&fq=%7B%21afts%7DTENANT_FILTER_FROM_JSON HTTP/1.1" 200 103
127.0.0.1 - - [19/Nov/2020:14:32:10 +0700] "GET /alfresco/s/api/people?filter=sup_dsm&maxResults=250&alf_ticket=TICKET_bc25963e5e279e411d0954da3 HTTP/1.1" 200 32
172.0.0.76 - - [19/Nov/2020:14:32:10 +0700] "GET /share/proxy/alfresco/api/people?filter=sup_dsm&maxResults=250 HTTP/1.1" 200 21
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:15 +0700] "POST /alfresco/service/api/solr/modelsdiff HTTP/1.1" 200 37
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:15 +0700] "POST /alfresco/service/api/solr/modelsdiff HTTP/1.1" 200 37
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/aclchangesets?fromTime=1609401496112&toTime=1609405096112&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 245
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/aclchangesets?fromTime=1609401496112&toTime=1609405096112&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 245
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/aclchangesets?fromTime=1609405096112&toTime=1609412296112&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 132
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/transactions?fromCommitTime=1636885490749&toCommitTime=1636889090749&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 256
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/transactions?fromCommitTime=1636885490749&toCommitTime=1636889090749&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 256
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/transactions?fromCommitTime=1636889090749&toCommitTime=1636896290749&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 120
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/aclchangesets?fromTime=1609401496112&toTime=1609405096112&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 245
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/aclchangesets?fromTime=1609401496112&toTime=1609405096112&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 245
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/aclchangesets?fromTime=1609405096112&toTime=1609412296112&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 132
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/transactions?fromCommitTime=1636885490749&toCommitTime=1636889090749&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 256
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/transactions?fromCommitTime=1636885490749&toCommitTime=1636889090749&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 256
127.0.0.1 - CN=Alfresco Repository Client, OU=Unknown, O=Alfresco Software Ltd., L=Maidenhead, ST=UK, C=GB [19/Nov/2020:14:32:19 +0700] "GET /alfresco/service/api/solr/transactions?fromCommitTime=1636889090749&toCommitTime=1636896290749&maxResults=2000 HTTP/1.1" 200 120
```

Comment: I guess you have an index issue. The log you appended is from the access log. Did you check with the node browser if the user node exists and if you can search the node in the node browser?

Comment: I found the user on DB but not API

Comment: Then should try a reindex.

Comment: I try to use this
https://docs.alfresco.com/search-community/tasks/solr-reindex.html
But my category and tag lost and can't create

Comment: sorry - but that's not the way we could help you. 

- [how-to-ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)
- [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Answer (score 0):

You can verify that by using the database query or by using the rest api call.

```
Retrieve the number of users in the Repository

SELECT count(*)
FROM alf_node AS n,
  alf_qname AS q
WHERE n.type_qname_id=q.id
  AND q.local_name='person';
  
  
 http://localhost:8080/alfresco/s/api/people?maxResults=500
```

[image]

Comment: I found the user on DB but not API

Comment: https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/license-authorize.html. Try to authorize the users first

Answer (score 0):

Also just do a wild search in the users section as below and try to find out the created user over there.
[image]

Comment: Try to authorize users first- https://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/tasks/license-authorize.html